# How do you prove the validity of this formula for $H(n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm looking for a proof of the identity

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{2n}+\pi\int_{0}^{1} (1-u)\cot{\pi u}\left(1-\cos{2\pi n u}\right)\,du.$$

There is a generalization of this formula for $H_k(n)$, if somebody can provide me with insights on how it's derived, I'd really appreciate.

Remember there is really no nice formulas for $H(n)$, this is the very first one, so this deserves some effort from my fellow MOers.

So here's the real challenge: $H_{2k+1}(n)=\frac{1}{2n^{2k+1}}-\frac{(-1)^{k}(2\pi)^{2k+1}}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{B_{2k-2j}\left(2-2^{2k-2j}\right)}{(2k-2j)!(2j+1)!}u^{2j+1}f(u,n)\,du$,

where $f(u,n)=\cot{\pi u}\left[1-\cos{2\pi n(1-u)}\right]$

Comment: Ok, I get it, so here's the real challenge: $H_{2k+1}(n)=\frac{1}{2n^{2k+1}}-\frac{(-1)^{k}(2\pi)^{2k+1}}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{B_{2k-2j}\left(2-2^{2k-2j}\right)}{(2k-2j)!(2j+1)!}u^{2j+1}f(u,n)\,du$, where $f(u,n)=\cot{\pi u}\left[1-\cos{2\pi n(1-u)}\right]$

Comment: Once again, this is not a challenge site. If you have new results, go ahead and publish them. Every year about 100 thousand papers appear in pure mathematics. Most active members of this site publish regularly, simply because they are research mathematicians. With all that said, I enjoyed proving your identity. You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's second display is a variant of an identity that appears in Section 3.7 of this [recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07877). It can be proved directly as follows (I will rename $k$ to $\ell$ in order to avoid confusion with the summation variable $k$ in the OP's first display). First, it is straightforward to see, e.g. by induction or by summing the relevant finite geometric series on the unit circle, that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin 2\pi ku =\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\pi nu+\frac{1}{2}(\cot{\pi u})(1-\cos{2\pi n u}).$$
Therefore, introducing the polynomials
$$P_\ell(u):=(-1)^\ell\sum_{j=0}^{\ell}\frac{B_{2\ell-2j}\left(2-2^{2\ell-2j}\right)}{(2\ell-2j)!(2j+1)!}u^{2j+1},\qquad\ell\geq 0,$$
it suffices to prove that
$$\int_0^1 P_\ell(u)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du=\frac{-1}{(2\pi k)^{2\ell+1}},\qquad k\geq 1,\quad\ell\geq 0.\tag{1}$$
To see this, we proceed by induction on $\ell$. For $\ell=0$, $(1)$ follows easily from $P_0(u)=u$. Let us now assume that $\ell\geq 1$ and $(1)$ holds with $\ell-1$ in place of $\ell$. Using the identity (which also appears in Section 3.7 of the [mentioned preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07877))
$$\frac{\sin xu}{\sin x}=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty P_\ell(u)x^{2\ell},\qquad |x|<\pi,\tag{2}$$ 
we see readily that $P_\ell(0)=P_\ell(1)=0$ (for $\ell\geq 1$).
Therefore, integrating by parts twice,
\begin{align*}\int_0^1 P_\ell(u)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du
&=\frac{1}{2\pi k}\int_0^1 P'_\ell(u)(\cos 2\pi ku)\,du\\[8pt]
&=\frac{-1}{(2\pi k)^2}\int_0^1 P''_\ell(u)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du\\[8pt]
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi k)^2}\int_0^1 P_{\ell-1}(u)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du\\[8pt]
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi k)^2}\cdot\frac{-1}{(2\pi k)^{2\ell-1}}=\frac{-1}{(2\pi k)^{2\ell+1}}.
\end{align*}
The proof is complete.

**Added.** For an alternative proof of $(1)$, observe that for $|x|<\pi$ we have by $(2)$
\begin{align*}\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\left(\int_0^1 P_\ell(u)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du\right)x^{2\ell}&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sin xu}{\sin x}\right)(\sin 2\pi ku)\,du\\[6pt]
&=\frac{-2\pi k}{(2\pi k)^2-x^2}\\[6pt]
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty\frac{-x^{2\ell}}{(2\pi k)^{2\ell+1}}.
\end{align*}
Now compare the two sides.